# Windows 10 Quick access jumping to another folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In the Windows 10 **Quick access** menu, whenever I select the Downloads/Documents/Pictures folder it will automatically jump to its related folder. This is very annoying and I couldn't find any options to stop this behavior.

It's happening to me on a brand new Windows 10 installation (build 10586.164).
I made a crappy screen recording of my problem where it keeps jumping:

[http://i.imgur.com/Tk25o3R.webm](https://i.imgur.com/Tk25o3R.webm)

Comment: What will be your desired behavior then? Or do you mean the jump of the highlighting?

Comment: I want it to not jump to a different folder when I select a folder. Especially when I have a lot of folders in the Quick access menu it will jump all the way down in the scroll list, away from the Quick access menu.

Yes, I mean the selection/highlighting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure the circled option is not ticked. If it's already the case, try to toggle it (tick -> ok -> untick -> ok).

[image]

If it still doesn't work, then your Windows is messed up somehow.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I didn't know that there was an option for it after all. I still was confused it happened with a clean installation, but I did log in first with my Microsoft Account.  
Googling for the problem was kind of difficult, or I wasn't searching in the right way.

Comment:  Nice answers guy.