# Prevent subfolders in Quick Access pinned folders from causing the Navigation Pane to jump to it's location

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-quick-access

I turned off the jumping from the Quick Access area to the folder in the drive for 
a user of ours, through use of the accepted answer in [Windows 10 Quick access jumping to another folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1059920/windows-10-quick-access-jumping-to-another-folder), but this user would also prefer subfolders of these pinned folders to not jump to their drive-based location, the same as the folders that were actually pinned did before the aforementioned link was found.

Haven't ever seen an option for this, and from my many use of Windows I would presume there isn't, but just in case putting the question out on here.